# Can I set background image and opacity in the same property?

Tags: css

I can see in CSS references [how to set image transparency](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp) and [how to set a background image](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp). But how can I combine these two in order to set a transparent background image?

I have an image that I'd like to use as a background, but it is too bright - I'd like to turn the opacity down to about 0.2. How can I do this?

```css
#main {
    background-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/tandem.jpg); 
}
```

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Two methods:

1. Convert to PNG and make the original image 0.2 opacity
2. (Better method) have a `<div>` that is `position: absolute;` before `#main` and the same height as `#main`, then apply the background-image and `opacity: 0.2; filter: alpha(opacity=20);`.

Comment: Yeah, the big problem with a PNG is the size. It is likely going to be really large. Now that we can specify `opacity: ...` in all browsers, it way better!

Comment: You'd be surprised what you can squeeze out of PNG. For instance, at 0.2 opacity, you're probably not going to be picking out many details, so you can convert to Indexed-PNG. I actually use this on my own website, and it squashes a 1920x1080 background image to just under 250kb in size.

Comment: You better add z-index: -1 to that position:absolute, in order to allow using bottoms above the overlay. Good answer.

Comment: You can also use WebP - it supports transparency and the file size is much smaller than PNG. All major browsers except Safari now support WebP. You can serve WebP to supporting browsers and PNG to Safari.

Comment: `background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.5), rgba(255,255,255,.5)), url("https://kusalthiwanka.github.io/images/kusal.jpg");`

Answer (score 370):

```css
#main {
    position: relative;
}
#main:after {
    content : "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url(/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/tandem.jpg); 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity : 0.2;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: Generated content from IE8 up. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent, use filter property for IE8. http://caniuse.com/#search=opacity

Comment: Note, this will not work with an `<img/>` tag.  Instead, use a `<span/>`, set the main element as inline-block, add a `:before` for the background image (copy from `:after`), then change the `:after` to use the foreground image and set opacity as 1.

Comment: Width and height can be 100% for the `:before` and `:after` elements.  The main element should have the specific width and height set.

Comment: I added a "z-index: -1" to the CSS. That way the background image is affected by the opacity, not the rest of the contents of #main

Comment: Here's an example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lfhgp/ I've added in `background-size: cover` for a non-repeated background image.

Comment: I use `:before` instead of `:after` and then I don't have to tamper with the `z-index` because `:before` ends up below the main contents automatically. (Currently tested in Chrome and FF.)

Comment: @KajMagnus If you do that, then everything after that doesn't get shown. Try having an opacity of 1.0, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: i had to add `right: 0;` and `bottom: 0;` as well, otherwise the pseudo-element had a size of 0x0 px.

Comment: If you are getting a repeated background image, you may want/need to add `background-repeat: no-repeat; background-attachment: fixed; background-position: center;` within **#main:after {...}**.

Comment: If you are looking for a background for `html` that fills the window and expands to fit content, just add `position: fixed`.

Comment: I found using `:before` caused some odd text-selection issues, as if the cursor were a line lower than it should've been. Likely because of the `content: ""` part, which without this doesn't work. Sticking with `:after`.

Answer (score 108):

Solution with 1 div and NO transparent image:

You can use the multibackground CSS3 feature and put two backgrounds: one with the image, another with a transparent panel over it (cause I think there's no way to set directly the opacity of the background image):

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7) 100%), url(bg.png) repeat 0 0, url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png) repeat 0 0;

background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 100%), url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png) repeat 0 0;

background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.7)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,0.7))), url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png) repeat 0 0;

background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 100%), url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png) repeat 0 0;

background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 100%), url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png) repeat 0 0;

background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 100%), url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png) repeat 0 0;

background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.7) 100%), url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png) repeat 0 0;
```

You can't use `rgba(255,255,255,0.5)` because alone it is only accepted on the back, so you I've used generated gradients for each browser for this example (that's why it is so long). But the concept is the following:

```
background: tranparentColor, url("myImage");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pBVsD/1/

Comment: This will only work if the background is a solid color, if you have PNG24 which is a background and you want it to have opacity (on hover for example) then this will not work, and you will have to use the pseudo-element method, which is actually better since it could be used in IE 8 and up.

Answer (score 75):

## Simple solution

if you need to set the gradient to **background-image** only:

```
background-image: url(IMAGE_URL); /* fallback for older browsers */

background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.6) 100%), url(IMAGE_URL);
```

Comment: Image moves slightly to the top. Does it have a fix?

Comment: You can also use RGBA 255,255,255 
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0.6) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0.6) 100%), url(IMAGE_URL);

Comment: @Roman You may set the rgba color component to the value used as background-color in the element or its embedding parent (tested on Chrome 58.0.3029.81, Edge 38.14393.0.0).

Comment: How to use with hex?

Answer (score 47):

I saw this and in CSS3 you can now place code in like this. Lets say I want it to cover the whole background I would do something like this. Then with `hsla(0,0%,100%,0.70)` or rgba you use a white background with whatever percentage saturation or opacity to get the look you desire.

```
.body{
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url(../images/Store1.jpeg);
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: hsla(0,0%,100%,0.70);
    background-blend-mode: overlay;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Adding background-color and background-blend-mode did the trick for me. Now i have a div with a opacity that does not affect its children!

Comment: this is Great! I created a jquery function to change the opacity on scroll, creating a color over a background image as you scroll down. $(function(){
 $(window).scroll(function(){
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  var current = 0;
  var now = (current-scroll)/7;
  $('.slide').css('background-position', '50% ' + now + 'px');
  var color = Math.round(scroll/7)/100;
  $('.slide').css('background-color','rgba(128, 45, 87, ' + color + ')');
 });
});

Answer (score 12):

You can use CSS psuedo selector ::after to achieve this. Here is a working demo.

[image]

```css
.bg-container{
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
}
.bg-container .content{
  position: absolute;
  z-index:999;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.bg-container::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index:-99;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hp53k.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-container">
   <div class="content">
     <h1>Background Opacity 0.4</h1>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue. I had an image and wanted to reduce the transparency and have a black background behind the image. Instead of reducing the opacity or creating a black background or any secondary div I set a linear-gradient to the image all on one line:

```html
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 100%), url("/img/picture.png");
```

Answer (score 3):

I have used the answer of @Dan Eastwell and it works very well. The code is similar to his code but with some additions.

```css
.granddata {
    position: relative;
    margin-left :0.5%;
    margin-right :0.5%;
}
.granddata:after {
    content : "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url("/Images/blabla.jpg");
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.2;
    z-index: -1;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A great way to do it for a simple image is to do it using only CSS to set the background of the HTML element like so.

```css
HTML {
    background: url('http://www.earthtimes.org/newsimage/eat-lead-by-example-obesity-expert-tells-parents_139.jpg');
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

If you want to get *fancy*, and set its opacity, then, in IE9+*, you can set a transparent background color of the body. This works by overlaying semitransparent white to make the image whiter, and appear to be brighter. For example, white with 75% opacity (`rgba(255,255,255,.75)`) would produce the following effect.

```css
HTML {
  background: url('http://www.earthtimes.org/newsimage/eat-lead-by-example-obesity-expert-tells-parents_139.jpg');
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et id, maecenas a convallis, elit facilisi congue augue id ac. Suscipit luctus egestas rutrum, amet tincidunt porttitor ante convallis magna, vivamus amet at turpis, ante lacinia blandit vel metus mauris rutrum. Ipsum nam adipiscing.
  Est sapien quis sem vestibulum, quis cubilia turpis, suspendisse mattis vehicula enim risus pede, placerat suspendisse dui. Convallis nostrud pede, mollit lobortis, ornare ipsum tempor faucibus tortor, vel pede, porttitor nulla nonummy vestibulum purus.
  Eros placerat tenetur augue ipsum aliquam, pellentesque congue condimentum sed vitae lectus.</p>
<p>Aliquam venenatis curabitur pellentesque sociosqu quam. Tincidunt id erat vestibulum in, est fermentum ipsum et augue, nascetur etiam. Lorem elit, sed donec, leo vivamus ac id enim faucibus vel. Nullam sit feugiat sed massa consectetuer auctor, nulla
  et erat lacinia nec, eget ut ante nullam est non in, elit porttitor in in donec eget porttitor. Interdum ultricies sem morbi facilisis nibh erat. Id suspendisse, sed tincidunt fringilla sit, sapien odio vel, at culpa augue sed taciti neque inceptos,
  massa class non. Vel tristique condimentum at pellentesque, commodo nulla sagittis rhoncus lorem. Viverra maecenas tellus pretium urna mauris proin, vel libero morbi, ante volutpat vestibulum augue. Itaque leo mauris turpis, vivamus nisl congue nisl
  nulla in turpis, eget vitae accumsan dolor ipsum leo venenatis, feugiat vehicula in risus, donec eu pede vivamus itaque nam. Justo amet vitae pellentesque sed, posuere fusce sapien, sed nam placerat libero sed etiam curabitur, suspendisse justo, amet
  porttitor.</p>
<p>Condimentum eget. Sem elementum a et mauris sem a, velit justo consectetuer in turpis mauris, sit sed elit cum, fusce suspendisse pretium dictum, mattis dui tortor tellus. Volutpat ut ante lorem nec laoreet aliquam, lorem est magna amet, integer mauris
  purus tellus. Porta enim repellendus aliquam eros. Turpis posuere elementum suscipit wisi lobortis, nec nunc consequat dictum ut unde at, mi lorem amet nunc. Cubilia pede, integer dolor, eget platea felis elit enim rhoncus, integer proin quam in ipsum
  lorem, diam curabitur netus pretium pellentesque. Donec rutrum ultrices placerat, curabitur maecenas, feugiat pede varius accumsan quam lorem, dui et dictumst asperiores nulla, vivamus urna nam leo libero. Posuere non convallis amet justo parturient,
  imperdiet consectetuer arcu praesent cursus risus, quis pretium dolor.</p>
```

- **Tip:** notice how  the HTML is `position: relative`, while the body is `position: absolute`. This is to prevent the background color of the body from behaving more like a highlighter of the text in the body.

This could even be expanded to something comparable to, but still **very** distinct from, CSS filters by changing around the body's RGBA color background. For example, `rgba(0,255,0,.75)` would create a very green tint as you can see in the code snippet.

```css
HTML {
    background: url('http://www.earthtimes.org/newsimage/eat-lead-by-example-obesity-expert-tells-parents_139.jpg');
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
body {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: rgba(0,255,0,.75);
}
```

```html
<p>Aliquam venenatis curabitur pellentesque sociosqu quam. Tincidunt id erat vestibulum in, est fermentum ipsum et augue, nascetur etiam. Lorem elit, sed donec, leo vivamus ac id enim faucibus vel. Nullam sit feugiat sed massa consectetuer auctor, nulla et erat lacinia nec, eget ut ante nullam est non in, elit porttitor in in donec eget porttitor. Interdum ultricies sem morbi facilisis nibh erat. Id suspendisse, sed tincidunt fringilla sit, sapien odio vel, at culpa augue sed taciti neque inceptos, massa class non. Vel tristique condimentum at pellentesque, commodo nulla sagittis rhoncus lorem. Viverra maecenas tellus pretium urna mauris proin, vel libero morbi, ante volutpat vestibulum augue. Itaque leo mauris turpis, vivamus nisl congue nisl nulla in turpis, eget vitae accumsan dolor ipsum leo venenatis, feugiat vehicula in risus, donec eu pede vivamus itaque nam. Justo amet vitae pellentesque sed, posuere fusce sapien, sed nam placerat libero sed etiam curabitur, suspendisse justo, amet porttitor.</p>
<p>Condimentum eget. Sem elementum a et mauris sem a, velit justo consectetuer in turpis mauris, sit sed elit cum, fusce suspendisse pretium dictum, mattis dui tortor tellus. Volutpat ut ante lorem nec laoreet aliquam, lorem est magna amet, integer mauris purus tellus. Porta enim repellendus aliquam eros. Turpis posuere elementum suscipit wisi lobortis, nec nunc consequat dictum ut unde at, mi lorem amet nunc. Cubilia pede, integer dolor, eget platea felis elit enim rhoncus, integer proin quam in ipsum lorem, diam curabitur netus pretium pellentesque. Donec rutrum ultrices placerat, curabitur maecenas, feugiat pede varius accumsan quam lorem, dui et dictumst asperiores nulla, vivamus urna nam leo libero. Posuere non convallis amet justo parturient, imperdiet consectetuer arcu praesent cursus risus, quis pretium dolor.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et id, maecenas a convallis, elit facilisi congue augue id ac. Suscipit luctus egestas rutrum, amet tincidunt porttitor ante convallis magna, vivamus amet at turpis, ante lacinia blandit vel metus mauris rutrum. Ipsum nam adipiscing. Est sapien quis sem vestibulum, quis cubilia turpis, suspendisse mattis vehicula enim risus pede, placerat suspendisse dui. Convallis nostrud pede, mollit lobortis, ornare ipsum tempor faucibus tortor, vel pede, porttitor nulla nonummy vestibulum purus. Eros placerat tenetur augue ipsum aliquam, pellentesque congue condimentum sed vitae lectus.</p>
```

- **Tip:** RGBA corresponds to **R**ed**G**reen**B**lue**A**lpha. So, the browser interprets `rgba(0,255,0,.75)` as something exemplified by `{red:0, green:255, blue:0, alpha:'75%'}`.

*A full compatibility table can be found at [Can I Use.](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-colors) However, please also note that you need to click the "Show All" to see that IE9 supports it.

## Addendum

Since I have already answered the question but I have more I want to add, I am titling this section addendum and having it add some potentially helpful information. So, to extrapolate even further on the content above, you could use an SVG as a background image to do wicked awesome things. For example, you could create a loading screen background featuring a cool website icon as you can see in the example of a base64 encoded SVG below.

```css
HTML {
    background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    background-size: cover;
}
body {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

```html
<p>Condimentum eget. Sem elementum a et mauris sem a, velit justo consectetuer in turpis mauris, sit sed elit cum, fusce suspendisse pretium dictum, mattis dui tortor tellus. Volutpat ut ante lorem nec laoreet aliquam, lorem est magna amet, integer mauris purus tellus. Porta enim repellendus aliquam eros. Turpis posuere elementum suscipit wisi lobortis, nec nunc consequat dictum ut unde at, mi lorem amet nunc. Cubilia pede, integer dolor, eget platea felis elit enim rhoncus, integer proin quam in ipsum lorem, diam curabitur netus pretium pellentesque. Donec rutrum ultrices placerat, curabitur maecenas, feugiat pede varius accumsan quam lorem, dui et dictumst asperiores nulla, vivamus urna nam leo libero. Posuere non convallis amet justo parturient, imperdiet consectetuer arcu praesent cursus risus, quis pretium dolor.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, et id, maecenas a convallis, elit facilisi congue augue id ac. Suscipit luctus egestas rutrum, amet tincidunt porttitor ante convallis magna, vivamus amet at turpis, ante lacinia blandit vel metus mauris rutrum. Ipsum nam adipiscing. Est sapien quis sem vestibulum, quis cubilia turpis, suspendisse mattis vehicula enim risus pede, placerat suspendisse dui. Convallis nostrud pede, mollit lobortis, ornare ipsum tempor faucibus tortor, vel pede, porttitor nulla nonummy vestibulum purus. Eros placerat tenetur augue ipsum aliquam, pellentesque congue condimentum sed vitae lectus.</p>
<p>Aliquam venenatis curabitur pellentesque sociosqu quam. Tincidunt id erat vestibulum in, est fermentum ipsum et augue, nascetur etiam. Lorem elit, sed donec, leo vivamus ac id enim faucibus vel. Nullam sit feugiat sed massa consectetuer auctor, nulla et erat lacinia nec, eget ut ante nullam est non in, elit porttitor in in donec eget porttitor. Interdum ultricies sem morbi facilisis nibh erat. Id suspendisse, sed tincidunt fringilla sit, sapien odio vel, at culpa augue sed taciti neque inceptos, massa class non. Vel tristique condimentum at pellentesque, commodo nulla sagittis rhoncus lorem. Viverra maecenas tellus pretium urna mauris proin, vel libero morbi, ante volutpat vestibulum augue. Itaque leo mauris turpis, vivamus nisl congue nisl nulla in turpis, eget vitae accumsan dolor ipsum leo venenatis, feugiat vehicula in risus, donec eu pede vivamus itaque nam. Justo amet vitae pellentesque sed, posuere fusce sapien, sed nam placerat libero sed etiam curabitur, suspendisse justo, amet porttitor.</p>
```

- **Tip:** The `background-size: cover` CSS causes the SVG logo in the background to be resized to the size of the HTML element.

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS add...

```
 filter: opacity(50%);
```

In JavaScript use...

```
 element.style.filter='opacity(50%)';
```

NB: Add vendor prefixes as required but Chromium should be fine without.

Answer (score 0):

I just added position=absolute,top=0,width=100% in the #main and set the opacity value to the #background

```
#main{height:100%;position:absolute; top:0;width:100%}
#background{//same height as main;background-image:url(image URL);opacity:0.2}
```

I applied the background to a div before the main.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add background linear-gradient with opacity and background image.
In this example, I'm using a white background linear gradient. But you can use any rgba color

```
background: linear-gradient(rgba(255,255,255,.5), rgba(255,255,255,.5)), url("https://kusalthiwanka.github.io/images/kusal.jpg");
```

Answer (score -1):

Well the only CSS way of doing only background transparency is via `RGBa` but since you want to use an image I would suggest using Photoshop or Gimp to make the image transparent and then using it as the background.

Comment: This is not correct, there is a CSS3 declaration: `opactiy: 1;`, not just RGBa.

Comment: What he is saying is setting the `background-image` style on a container and then setting an `opacity` style on the same element. That would also make the text and other contents of that element transparent. Try this out if you don't believe me: http://www.w3schools.com/Css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_transparency

Answer (score -1):

I came across this post as I had the same issue then I thought why mess about with css, adjusting values and hitting refresh when you can easily adjust the opacity in Photoshop? Copy the image, paste it as a new layer then move the opacity slider.

Comment: ArtB got it right w/ the last note. This is a perfectly fine solution for another problem. There are times when this isn't the right solution and this is one of them.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue and I just took the background image with photoshop and created a new .png with the opacity I needed. Problem solved without worrying about if my CSS worked accross all devices & browsers