# Set page background image opacity

Tags: html, css, opacity

How to set background image for entire page opacity to 0.4 ?

I tried with

```
html { 
  background: url(img01.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

   opacity: 0.4;
   filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

but it set all element's on page opacity and i only want opacity of img01.jpg ??

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @user3739658 Firefox 30.0

Comment: img01.jpg is background of html or used image in your HTML.

Comment: This theme is the same as - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183948/css-set-background-image-with-opacity

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806000/transparent-background-but-not-the-content-text-images-inside-it-in-css-on?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without changing the image, this is the way I would do it.

Using pseudo element positioned `fixed` or `absolute`:

```
html:after {
    content : "";
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: url(http://dummyimage.com/1000x1000/000/fff.png); 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity : 0.2;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

You can see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ppGxn/) for an sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set opacity on a background image.

Instead, you could:

1. Make the background a semi-transparent PNG with the desired level of opacity.  Depending on the size of the background this may not be a great solution as PNGs have a much larger filesize footprint than JPGs.
2. If the transparency is intended to be over a solid color (i.e. white or black) you could add a solid/flat background gradient on top of the `background-image` using `rgba()` colors to mimic the desired opacity (e.g. if you wanted the background image to have 60% opacity, add a 40% opacity black flat background gradient that isn't actually a gradient on top).
3. Add your `background-image` to a psuedo-element like `::after` that is absolutely positioned to fill the containing element and manipulate the `opacity` of this image-only "fake background" layer.

Answer (score -1):

when you have using opacity in parent class then it is apply over parent class and child class also. so u have use the rgba color code in place of image.