# CSS background color not working in hover state

Tags: html, css

When I hover over the image the play button shows and the `background-color` and `opacity` of `.youTubeVideo` changes.

However, this does not happen when you hover over just the play button. How can I make the `background-color` and `opacity` of `.youTubeVideo` change when hovering over the play button?

```css
.youTubeVideo:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: green;
}
.videoThum:hover {
  background-color: green;
  background-image: url("http://s24.postimg.org/k69rptjk1/play_button.jpg");
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-3">
  <div class="videoThum">
    <a href="javascript:;" rel="https://www.youtube.com/embed/OSgvYZpO2xY" class="youTubeVideo">
      <img src="http://s8.postimg.org/jf407d2xh/saina_nehwal_syed.png" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="caption"><a href="#"><h2>2015 Syed Modi International</h2></a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>2015 Syed Modi International India Masters SF [WS]</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eyz3gsuj/2/)

Comment: Are you sure? http://jsfiddle.net/eyz3gsuj/1/

Comment: may be your image coverd teh entire background. That's why you can't able to see the background color. looks your `background-size:100% 100%` covers the entire area.

Comment: Am I the only one getting a non-working fiddle?

Comment: @connexo: me demo updated..

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai: is there any relation between background color and background-size?.. thanks

Comment: @saina use some transparent background image, then you will come to know.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai: here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/eyz3gsuj/4/ .. so why didn't show play button as green color, thanks

Comment: background color is displaying but hide backside of image. check  http://i.stack.imgur.com/fn32q.png

Comment: i want to show both image and color @ketan

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when you hover over the right side of `.videoThum` you are no longer hovering over `.youTubeVideo` so `.youTubeVideo:hover` wont take effect.

As `.videoThum` contains `.youTubeVideo` you can trigger the change to `.youTubeVideo` when `.videoThum` is hovered instead by changing `.youTubeVideo:hover` to `.videoThum:hover .youTubeVideo`.

```css
.videoThum:hover {
  background-color: green;
  background-image: url("http://s24.postimg.org/k69rptjk1/play_button.jpg");
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.videoThum:hover .youTubeVideo {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-3">
  <div class="videoThum">
    <a href="javascript:;" rel="https://www.youtube.com/embed/OSgvYZpO2xY" class="youTubeVideo">
      <img src="http://s8.postimg.org/jf407d2xh/saina_nehwal_syed.png" />
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="caption"><a href="#"><h2>2015 Syed Modi International</h2></a>
    <a href="#">
      <p>2015 Syed Modi International India Masters SF [WS]</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/bq9rgzap/

Comment: @saina In that case please check my edit to your question as it may not be exactly what you are after. You may want to roll it back or edit it with extra information. Please could you clarify exactly what it is about my answer that isn't fulfilling your criteria?

Answer (score 0):

Your background image is covering the whole element.

See this modified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eyz3gsuj/3/) with `background-size` changed to see the problem.

One way around this would be to use a `png` image with transparency or `pseudo` elements with `position:absolute`

See [CSS: set background image with opacity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183948/css-set-background-image-with-opacity)