# CSS opacity target background image only?

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS

```
.jumbotron {
  background: url('/background.svg');
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

but I want the opacity to target the background image only. At the moment it targets the whole jumbotron so the fonts etc. are also faded.

I've tried

```
.jumbotron {
  background: url('/background.svg');
  background: opacity: 0.5;
}
```

and

```
.jumbotron {
  background: url('/background.svg');
}
.jumbotron:img {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

but neither work.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183948/css-set-background-image-with-opacity and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997493/set-opacity-of-background-image-without-affecting-child-elements

Comment: You need to set the background as pseudo element ( `:before` / `:after`) and use opacity on this pseudo element only - Note, you can set a `z-index:-1;` to this pseudo element

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. What gets :before or :after? ... My current code is the 1st example, what do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

From [**CSS-tricks.com**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/):

There is no CSS property background-opacity, but you can fake it by inserting a pseudo element with regular opacity the exact size of the element behind it.

```
.jumbotron::after {
  content: "";
  background: url(/background.svg);
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;   
}
```

As isherwood mentioned in the comments, maybe you have to set your

```
.jumbotron {
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: @Wavemaster that causes the whole page to have a background of background.svg, not the jumbotron

Comment: You may need to do `.jumbotron {position: relative}` first.

Answer (score -1):

Set opacity:1 for anoter element in jumbotron like font etc.

Comment: That won't work, because the general opacity is already set to 0.5.