# giving background img an opacity

Tags: html, css, background-image, opacity

I'm trying to give my full page background-image an opacity but when I add the opacity code, my whole html get's an opacity of 0.4 exept the image.

```
html { 
  background: url(../img/bg2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

[Source](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

I tried to add opacity like this:

```
html { 
  background: url(../img/bg2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.4;
}
```

But as I said, my whole html turns 0.4

And I tried to add 0.4 after `background: url(../img/bg2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed 0.4;`  but my image just goes blank then.

How can I add 0.4 only to my background-image?

Comment: Find your Answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183948/css-set-background-image-with-opacity

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183948/css-set-background-image-with-opacity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `::after` pseudoclass:

```css
html::after {
  content: "";
  background: url(../img/bg2.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  opacity: 0.4;  
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: My bg-img just goes blank again

Comment: @Blank, see my updated code. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Set `opacity` for `body` also and try again :

```
body {
   opacity : 1;
}
```

Comment: why you place down vote, can you tell me?

Comment: If I set opacity on body, it still has the same effect, it doesn't change the img

Comment: can you place your code in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I use the `:after` psuedo element on the body tag in these cases, together with some absolute positioning and the opacity property: https://jsfiddle.net/kc0sf39r/

**HTML:**

```
<body>
  content
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    background: url("http://digital-photography-school.com/wp-content/uploads/flickr/205125227_3f160763a0_o.jpg") no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}
body:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: -99px;
    bottom: -99px;
    left: -99px;
    right: -99px;
    background-color: red;
    content: " ";
    opacity: 0.5;

}
```