# image dim and zoom with text

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have an image on which I have some texts. When I hover on the image, I want the image to dim and zoom in. That is working properly, but the problem I have is that the texts on my image get dimmed too as the image dims out. I don't want the text to dim out with the image. How can I achieve that?

Check [this Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/xEnJAPA7I5) for the code

**NOTE** : The image is placed as the background of the div that contains my texts

Comment: opacity affects all child elements, you would need to reorganize your layout code to make it so that the text element you want to use isn't a child element of the one being made transparent.

Comment: can u provide a cleaner code ?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: It's **not possible** to affect the opacity of a *background image*.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183948/css-set-background-image-with-opacity

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you set `opacity: .444;` on the parent wrapper, which applies to all children as well.

Instead of adjusting the opacity, I would fade in an overlay using a pseudo element and add `z-index` to the text wrapper to keep it above the overlay.

```
.hovereffect .overlay2 {
  /* your styles here */
  z-index: 1;
}

.hovereffect:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 250ms ease-in-out;
}
```

Then on hover, set the opacity to 1.

```
.hovereffect:hover:after { opacity: 1; }
```

Comment: @user765368 Can you post the code you tried? Thanks!