# Bootstrap jumbotron unclear text when opacity is applied

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to put the opacity of the background image, but the text seems to get blurry too..I just want the background to become opaque and not together with the text

[image]

Comment: share the code you're using to create that screenshot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [CSS Set Background Image with Opacity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183948/css-set-background-image-with-opacity). `opacity` will affect all child elements, not because it's inherited like `color`, but because the parent acts like a filter for all descendant elements.