# background image opacity with parent background color

Tags: html, css

The answers to *[CSS: set background image with opacity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183948/css-set-background-image-with-opacity)* describe a great background opacity fix using the pseudo element `:after`. However, if a parent division has a background color the transparent background image no longer shows, due to its use of `z-index: -1`. I've tried numerous work-arounds using this basic model to no avail.

Here is sample code.  Note that without `.locations_30 {background:white}` it works great.

```css
body {
  background-color: #fefbed;
  color: #444;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.locations_20 {
  position: relative;
}

.locations_20:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: url(../background_images/zenrockgarden_mod.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  opacity: 0.27;
}

.locations_30 {
  background: white;
  width: 800px;
  padding: 75px;
} /*parent division with color will overrun z-index: -1*/
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="locations_40">
    <div class="locations_30">
      <p class="locations_20">
        Super Sale Event We are happy to offer the following: etc,,, <br> We are happy to offer the following: etc,,, <br> We are happy to offer the following: etc,,, <br> We are happy to offer the following: etc,,, <br> We are happy to offer the following:
        etc,,, <br> We are happy to offer the following: etc,,, <br>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you update your `.locations_20` rule like this it will work

```
.locations_20 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;                    /*  added  */
}
```

Stack snippet

*Note, since the image doesn't load here at SO, I added `red` to the `.location_20`'s background so one can see it works*

```css
body {
  background-color: #fefbed;
  color: #444;
  font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.locations_20 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;                    /*  added  */
}

.locations_20:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: url(../background_images/zenrockgarden_mod.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  opacity: 0.27;
  background-color: red;         /*  temp. added so we can see it  */
}

.locations_30 {
  background: white;
  width: 800px;
  padding: 75px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="locations_40">
    <div class="locations_30">
      <p class="locations_20">
        Super Sale Event We are happy to offer the following: etc,,, <br> We are happy to offer the following: etc,,, <br> We are happy to offer the following: etc,,, <br> We are happy to offer the following: etc,,, <br> We are happy to offer the following:
        etc,,, <br> We are happy to offer the following: etc,,, <br>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```