# How do I set a background transparency I want in CSS?

Tags: html, css, opacity, photo

I try to put a photo under a block of text, but the colors of the photo are too strong and no longer understood what is written.
 I tried with comand : "opacity:0.5" but it doesn't work..

Comment: Add the HTML and CSS you have, in a snippet.

Comment: box-shadow,background-blend-mode,text-shadow and probably other method could be used. Clarify your question with enough code that demonstrate your issue if you really need help and efficient answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I set background image and opacity in the same property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183948/can-i-set-background-image-and-opacity-in-the-same-property)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the opacity of an element with the line `opacity: 0.5;` for half for instance, or you can set the background color as [an rgba color](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_rgba.asp), with the last variable indicating the desired alpha value